# Toggle / trigger display of a message with a button click

Tags: knockout.js

I have button called Fact. I want to display a message when someone clicks it. My HTML looks like this:

```html
<div id="option">
<button data-bind="click: displayMessage">Fact</button>
<div data-bind="if: displayMessage">You are right.</div>
```

My Javascript is this:

```
ko.applyBindings({
    displayMessage: ko.observable(false)
});
```

However, this is not working. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4):

You should pass a function to the [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) which sets displayMessage to true and you should use the [visible binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html).

```
<div id="option">
<button data-bind="click: function() { displayMessage(true); }">Fact</button>
<div data-bind="visible: displayMessage">You are right.</div>
```

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks.  Only used knockout for a few hours about 2 weeks ago.  I thought the click binding may have required a function, but then I thought that was too much boilerplate code for knockout.  Didn't think to use an anonymous function.

Comment: It is still not working. Can you provide the javascript for it, I want to re-check it.

Answer (score 1):

html:

```html
<div id="option">
<button data-bind="click: toggle">Fact</button>
<div data-bind="visible: displayMessage">You are right.</div>
```

js:

```html
var model = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.displayMessage = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggle = function(){
        self.displayMessage(!self.displayMessage());
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new model);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Jorgelig/43fca/